# How to write a for loop that uses both an iterator and an index counter?

Tags: c++, for-loop, stl

I have a function that looks like this:

```
void myclass::myfunc()
{
    int i;
    for( std::vector<Foo>::iterator it = var.begin(), i = 0; it < var.end(); it++, i++ )
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot convert from `int` to `std::_Vector_iterator<>`

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Use `++it` in order to increment iterator, because `it++` is the post-increment, and takes unnecessary time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
int i = 0;
for( std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it < v.end(); ++it, ++i){}
```

Comment: Marking this as an answer because it is the first one. Thank you.

Comment: why the inconsistency of `it++` and `++i`?

Comment: Actually, it would be better to only use the pre-increment; while it matters little for `i`, it might matter for `it` depending on how *fat* the iterator is.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler, it's not easy for a language to be as unreadable as C++ is ;)

Comment: @Shahbaz Indeed, it may even have to be specifically [designed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbolge) :-7

Answer (score 23):

The issue is with this part of the `for` loop:

```
std::vector<Foo>::iterator it = var.begin(), i = 0
```

C++ is interpreting this not as two comma-separated statements, but as a variable declaration for a variable named `it` that's an iterator, and as a new declaration of a variable `i` that's an iterator and initialized to 0.  The error is because you can't initialize a `vector` iterator to 0.

To fix this, you'll need to hoist the definition outside of the loop:

```
int i = 0;
std::vector<Foo>::iterator it = var.begin();
for(; it < var.end(); it++, i++ )
{
     // ...
}
```

Or move the initialization of `i` outside the loop:

```
int i = 0;
for( std::vector<Foo>::iterator it = var.begin(); it < var.end(); it++, i++ )
{
    // ...
}
```

Here's another option.  If you need to keep track of the index into the vector you're currently looking at, you could consider just using a counting for loop (without the iterator), or using just the iterator and using iterator subtraction to recover the index:

```
for (auto it = var.begin(); it != var.end(); ++it) {
    // current position is it - var.begin();
}
```

And, finally, if you have a C++20-compliant compiler, you could eliminate the iterator entirely and use an enhanced `for` loop in the following way:

```
/* Requires C++20 */
for (int i = 0; Foo f: var) {
    /* Do something worthwhile with f. */

    i++;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I thought that since I already initialized the iterator it will be variable initialization. Guess I was wrong. I will be using the fix #2. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `i=0;` part (at least inside the loop header).

Also, if you insist on doing this at all, consider using:

```
for (auto it : var)
```

or:

```
for (auto it = var.begin(); it != var.end(); ++it)
```

...instead. Since you're using a random access iterator anyway, what you have as `i` is equivalent to `it - var.begin()`. Conversely, you could just use:

```
for (int i=0; i<var.size(); i++)
```

...and get an iterator when needed as `var.begin() + i`.

Depending on what's in the body of the loop, you probably want to get rid of the loop entirely, and replace it with an algorithm though.

Comment: I'd love to use "auto", but I'm afraid that it's not compatible with OS X 10.6 XCode. Also I'm using iterators for efficiency, otherwise I'd definitely use just you 3rd form. Also what do you mean by "get rid of the loop". Could you clarify on how do I go thru the vector?

Answer (score 1):

Double iteration:

```
using std::begin; using std::end;
for (auto p = std::make_pair( begin(var), 0 ); p.first != end(var); ++p.first, ++p.second ) {
  /* ... */
}
```

double iteration with named indexes/iterators:

```
using std::begin; using std::end;
int i;
std::vector<Foo>::iterator it;
for (std::tie( it, i ) = std::make_pair( begin(var), 0 ); it != end(var); ++it, ++i ) {
  /* ... */
}
```

or bind the above pair on each iteration to better named variables:

```
using std::begin; using std::end;
for (auto p = std::make_pair( begin(var), 0 ); p.first != end(var); ++p.first, ++p.second ) {
  auto const& it = p.first;
  int i = p.second;
}
```